# Dynamically Create Web App In Azure Via Code

Tags: api, azure, subdomain, azure-web-app-service

Using Azure, is it possible to dynamically create a web app and copy/publish files to that new web app via an Azure API?  Here's my scenario:

1] Customer signs up for services in our application
2] We want to automatically generate a subdomain for the new customer (i.e. customername.ourapplication.com)
3] We want to create a copy of our core files for our web app into a new Azure Web App that the subdomain is pointed to.

Does this type of automation exist in Azure?  If not, what other services are out there that can do this?  We've seen it happen with other apps across the web and were wondering where we should start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the [Azure Resource Manager (ARM) API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/) allows your to provision and modify Azure web apps.

You can access the ARM API directly via the REST Api, via Powershell commandlets, or via the Azure CLI api

Comment: Exactly what I needed!  Thank you @Zain-Rizvi!